# Using a selection sort to sort an array of objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, object, selection

Currently, I have a basic selection sort written, and I need to have it sort an array of objects based on class members- if sorting for goalies[MAX_GOALIES].getWins(), the integers in getWins() need to be in descending order. Here's what I have so far for the sorting function:

```
void sortWins(int array[], int size)
{
    int maxIndex, maxValue;
    
    for (int start=0;start<(size -    1);start++)
    {
        maxIndex = start;
        maxValue = array[start];
        for (int index = start + 1; index < size; index ++)
        {
            if (array[index].getWins() > maxValue.getWins())
            {
                maxValue = array[index];
                maxIndex = index;
            }
        }
        swap(array[maxIndex], array[start]);
    }
}
```

how would i make sure that the sort function is sorting the class member getWins()?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: The function operates on an array of integers, not objects.  The `int` type does not have a member function `getWins()` (or _any_ member function for that matter, as it is not a class at all).  Is there a reason you're trying to hand-roll selection sort?  Why not define the appropriate operator and use `std::sort`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `std::sort` function, specifying the ordering criteria you want. A possible example could be:

```
std::sort(objectsVector.being(), objectsVector.end(), [](object a, object b) -> bool {
   return a.getWins() > b.getWins();
});
```

In this way in objectsVector you will be the list of objects, ordered in descending way.

If you want use a custom function, that implements the selection sort, you have to pass to this function an array of objects, instead of integers. Then inside your function, you will make the comparison on the value returned by getWins()